# Как повысить значения в каждой строке 2

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
 <Сотрудник Нпп="1">
 <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
 <Имя>***</Имя>
 <Отчество>***</Отчество>
 </Сотрудник>
 <Сотрудник Нпп="2">
 <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
 <Имя>***</Имя>
 <Отчество>***</Отчество>
 </Сотрудник>
 <Сотрудник Нпп="3">
 <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
 <Имя>***</Имя>
 <Отчество>***</Отчество>
```

Добрый вечер! Нужно повысить Нпп на 2000 в каждой строке. Можете помочь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте свой XML правильно сформированным: well-formed

Comment: Не могу задать новый вопрос. Извиняюсь за наглость, но могли бы Вы мне пошаговую инструкцию дать, чтоб я связал? Например, оба файла находятся у меня на рабочем столе и название файлов a.xml и b.xsl. Только пару раз приходилось пользоваться XML. Название файла может содержать русские буквы?

Comment: Русские буквы не должны быть проблемой. Я могу показать, как это сделать на c#. Пожалуйста, дайте мне знать, приемлемо ли это.

Comment: Приемлемо. Попытаюсь догнать)) я просто это никогда не делал, поэтому, я вообще не знаю где связать эти 2 файла. И если куда-то закидывать нужно их, то как выгрузить файл XML с нужным мне преобразованием. Спешки нет. Спасибо Вам

Comment: Я добавил в ответ XSLT обработку  в c#.

Comment: Можете использовать [msxsl](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) на Винде или [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/xsltproc.html) на Линуксе.

Comment: Олег Ткаченко nxslt: https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/nxslt.shtml

Comment: nxslt3: https://github.com/bbvcommon/bbv.Common/tree/master/tools/nxslt3

Comment: Спасибо большое. Попытаюсь щас догнать всё это))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал ваш XML правильно сформированным, добавив корневой элемент.

XSLT использует так называемый шаблон преобразования идентичности (Identity transform pattern).

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<root>
    <Сотрудник Нпп="1">
        <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
        <Имя>***</Имя>
        <Отчество>***</Отчество>
    </Сотрудник>
    <Сотрудник Нпп="2">
        <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
        <Имя>***</Имя>
        <Отчество>***</Отчество>
    </Сотрудник>
    <Сотрудник Нпп="3">
        <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
        <Имя>***</Имя>
        <Отчество>***</Отчество>
    </Сотрудник>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Сотрудник">
      <Сотрудник Нпп="{./@Нпп + 2000}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Сотрудник>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\input.xml";
    const string XSLTFILE = @"e:\Temp\Process.xslt";
    const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\output.xml";

    try
    {
        XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
        
        using (XmlReader src = XmlReader.Create(SOURCEXMLFILE))
        {
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load(XSLTFILE, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

            XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
            settings.IndentChars = "\t";
            // to remove BOM
            settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

            using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, settings))
            {
                xslt.Transform(src, xslArg, result, new XmlUrlResolver());
                result.Close();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Файл '{0}' создан.", OUTPUTXMLFILE);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Результат**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Сотрудник Нпп="2001">
    <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
    <Имя>***</Имя>
    <Отчество>***</Отчество>
  </Сотрудник>
  <Сотрудник Нпп="2002">
    <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
    <Имя>***</Имя>
    <Отчество>***</Отчество>
  </Сотрудник>
  <Сотрудник Нпп="2003">
    <Фамилия>***</Фамилия>
    <Имя>***</Имя>
    <Отчество>***</Отчество>
  </Сотрудник>
</root>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое